# Problem with displaying files in the folder

Tags: files, data-recovery, restore, input, output

I am using external HDD, where I got some photos.
My OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Maybe something wrong happened during copying photos from local drive on computer to the external one.

[image: folders on disc]

as you see folder has more than 500 photos, but when Im trying to open it:

[image: error]

I was trying to copy using `mv` and `cp` commands (separately, of course) to make those files back again to my computer, but only some of them came back. The process has stopped on the 1st 'damaged' file.

How to restore all of them? As you see, there are lots of them and I don't want to lose any of them.

PS. I removed disc for a sec and now I got only 67 files (still, cannot open it). What to do?

PS2. I also tried `gparted`, but no success.

Comment: IO or input/output errors can indicate hardware errors, you haven't said what OS/release you are using, so I'd start by trying to assess the health of your drive using your drives SMART (self monitoring analysis reporting technology) detail (ie. `smartctl`, `gnome-disks`, `gparted`, `kde partition manager` or whatever your unspecified OS has) to see health of disk(s), then plan approach.  If IO error is a failing drive, you need to plan approach carefully to maximize chance of getting data back, though problem may not be serious; thus my suggestion to check health first.

Comment: @guiverc, I tried gparted, as I wrote, now Im trying TESTDISK

Comment: If your disk is near death, you want to know this before you do anything, so you can spend any time left being as productive as possible with whatever 'life' is left in the drive. SMART gets health from chips and does no further damage (to platters or storage components), testdisk and making changes DOES; thus getting details of your problem is as stated, the first & best approach. You can then plan the safest way to get as much data as possible back.  With `gparted` or other tools, I meant to READ drive health; making no changes at all, nor attempts to read anything but health.

Comment: Drive could have been disconnected while still writing, resulting in file system damage. Try checking the file system first. Likely, this is a disk formatted with ntfs (file system of Windows), so then you need to attach the disk to Windows for check and repair.

Comment: Yes, as I checked it got NTFS, but attached to Windows shows that the folder is damaged and contains 0 files. I will check later, since the comp is occupied by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

not yet able to comment...

A lot of IFs here, but if in fact your external drive is failing:

You indicate you may have recently copied (or moved) the files from your internal drive.  If so, some or most may be recoverable from your internal drive. Files moved from, or deleted from a hard drive will be recoverable until the space is reused, overwritten with new files.

As such, for maximum chance of recovering every file, I'd recommend shutting down (to avoid writing any more new files). Then make a full copy of your internal drive:  either by booting your system from USB-bootable OS, or removing the drive and connecting it to an other Linux system (Windows will automatically mount, index, and possibly write to newly attached drives. We don't want that).
If comfortable learning about and using command line, 'dd' command is the tool of choice for copying a full disk to a backup file or spare disk drive. Just be 110% certain you specify correct source and destination, else you could overwrite your data.
Once you have this backup of the internal drive, you may resume using your original system knowing if you need it, you have a copy from which to attempt recovery of anything not recovered from your external drive.

If reading S.M.A.R.T. from external indicates imminent failure, your best chance of recovering most of the data is with recovery tools. Regular copy operations will often spend too much time retrying reads that may never succeed. Recovery tools will instead focus on recovering the most amount of data in the least amount of time, and least amount of stress on a failing drive. If you are comfortable with command line, look at ddrescue. (Note: debian package name is gddrescue, while the cli command is ddrescue.)